# How to fill image with repeated indices using the max value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using numpy array to create an image from a set of 3d points. The 3d points are projected to image coordinate and some of the points fall on the same indices `(x, y)` of the image. I just want to keep the point with maximum x value.

Let show it with an example:

```py
idx = array(
       [[3, 3], [7, 3],[0, 1],[0, 6],[6, 9],[8, 1],[7, 3],[8, 3],[8, 4],[9, 5]]
)
x_val = array([
       [0.17166161],
       [0.80913063],
       [0.52597124],
       [0.27078974],
       [0.35230144],
       [0.66411425],
       [0.28035714],
       [0.76413514],
       [0.27064702],
       [0.54131715]]
)

im[idx[:, 1], idx[:, 0]] = x_val
```

The problem I am facing is with the line that is there are two indices `[7, 3]` with different `x_val`, `[0.80913063, 0.28035714]` from which i want to retain the maximum i.e., `im[7, 3] = 0.80913063`. How can I do this with numpy?

Comment: is `im` a `dict` of points, and their `x_val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first sort the `x_val` array in acsending order and then assign to `im`. If an index occurs multiple times the last assignment, which is the highest value, will set the final value.

```
import numpy as np

im = np.zeros((10,10))
idx = np.array(
       [[3, 3], [7, 3],[0, 1],[0, 6],[6, 9],[8, 1],[7, 3],[8, 3],[8, 4],[9, 5]]
)
x_val = np.array([
       [0.17166161],
       [0.80913063],
       [0.52597124],
       [0.27078974],
       [0.35230144],
       [0.66411425],
       [0.28035714],
       [0.76413514],
       [0.27064702],
       [0.54131715]]
)

order = x_val.argsort(0)[:,0]
im[idx[order][:, 1], idx[order][:, 0]] = x_val[order][:,0]
```

Result:

```
[[0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.53 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.66 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.17 0.   0.   0.   0.81 0.76 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.27 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.54]
 [0.27 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.35 0.   0.   0.  ]]
```

(I used the indexing order from your OP, i.e. `idx[1]`, which is `[7,3]`, will go into `im[3,7]` so that `im[3, 7] == 0.80913063`)